# Get right type of a photo in PHP

Tags: php, upload, photo

I've been tyring to upload photos on a website via a registeration form.

However, my program at first was expecting ".jpg" photos.

Whenever I renamed my photo from ".png" to ".jpg" I ended with a black photo.

How could I avoid having a black photo when extension is changed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions are not arbitrary.  You can't just change them and expect the underlying data to change.

You'll need to convert your photo from a PNG to a JPEG using either desktop software like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), or allow the user to upload the PNG and use PHP's [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library to convert them on your server.

Comment: I believe the default photo file viewer app in Windows will export one common file format as another; I know the OS X Preview app will.

Comment: That would qualify as using desktop software to convert it - albeit software that's embedded in the OS.

Comment: My point is, using GIMP for such a trivial conversion is probably overkill.

Comment: OP may be using an OS or version that doesn't support it.  GIMP is cross-platform, so I hedged my bets.  It's also a very useful tool to have around anyway.  :-)

Comment: There is no way to detect an underlying extension and act accordingly ?